# Add Flipmove to Material Table but not working

Tags: reactjs, material-table

This is my code for customize material table with react-flip-move animation when row change. But it's not working.

```
components={{
              Body: rowData => {
                return (
                  <FlipMove staggerDurationBy={30} duration={750} delay={30}>
                    <MTableBody {...rowData} />
                  </FlipMove>
                )
              },
```

I'm trying to research, and notice that, the way to make it run like expected

```
<tbody>
<FlipMove staggerDurationBy={30} duration={750} delay={30}>
    <tr></tr>
 </FlipMove>
</tbody>
```

But really I don't know how to custom it in material table.